# If function $f\in C^{1,\alpha} (D)$ (Holder spaces) with D is an open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then can we have $f$ is piecewise continuos function?

Tags: functional-analysis

If  function $f\in C^{1,\alpha} (D)$ (Holder spaces) with D is an open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then can we have that $f$ is piecewise continuos function?

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Comment: If the set is open, then $f$ is continuous on the open set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every continuous function is  piecewise continuous also ;)

As an example of a function $f\in C^{1,1}$ with $f\not\in C^2$ serves
$$
f(x) = |x|\cdot x
$$
with $f'(x) = |x|$.